# How to overwrite paypal form when it encrypted?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Slam 
Iam working on web site that take fees for accounts, any way it was perfect when testing in sandbox environment.
can i make encrypted button and overwrite the amount and the user ID in the form ?

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">                   
                  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MY_Business_ACOUNT">
                  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
                  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Subscribe for SMLE">
                  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $sub_fees; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
                  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
                  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url("ipn_success");?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo base_url("ipn_cancel");?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
                  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo base_url("ipn");?>">
                  <input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/img/paypal.png"); ?>"
                    border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"
                    width = "400" height = "200"
                  >

  </form>
```

what is the best solution to keep this form secure ?

i used [IPN API](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN)

Comment: It says what problem in `$errmsg`?

Comment: i fix the problem with $errmsg, but my question is still there, how can i make this form secure ? and change the values custom field and the amount field !

Comment: You've removed the most important part. The question.

Comment: the question is still there , how can i make it secure

Comment: What aspect of it isn't secure? And in your title do you mean 'override'?